# Multiple columns in a single listagg

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Is it possible to add multiple columns in a single listagg function?
I have a query that returns the result you can see in the screenshot below. First yellow highlighted result is what I have now. I want the second yellow highlighted result.

[image]

Comment: This is not listAgg, it's a simple concatenation. Are you using Sql Server or oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `LISTAGG`, you just need to concatenate the strings:

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT contractorno,
       fruits || stock_type || stockno AS stockinfo
FROM   (
  SELECT contractorno,
         fruits,
         stock_type,
         stockno
  FROM   your_query
)
```

In SQL Server the string concatenation operator is `+` instead of Oracle's `||`.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle**

```
SELECT contractorno
    ,fruits || '-' || stock_type || '-' || stockno AS stockinfo
FROM (
--your query--
    )q
```

**SQL-Server**

```
SELECT contractorno, 
       Concat (fruits, '-', stock_type, '-', stockno) AS stockinfo 
FROM   (--yourquery--
    ) q
```